# Rails 4.2.5, simple_form, hstore, nested forms - Hstore Hash not persisting on save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, simple-form, nested-forms

I'm struggling to understand what's going on when I save my large-ish form - none of the Hstore parameters are saved to the database. Can someone point out what I presume to be the obvious error? (I've quickly trimmed a lot of the output to keep it concise as possible.

There's no console output, and it's not complaining about unpermitted params or anything. `equipment` field on the `discipline` model is the hstore column.

Given my strong params settings:

```
params.require(:profile).permit(
  :id,
  :user_id,
  :gender,
  :dob,
  ..snip..
  disciplines_attributes: [
    :id,
    :profile_id,
    :discipline_type,
    :distance_in_meters_per_week,
    ..snip..
    :equipment => [
      :time_trial_bike,
      :road_bike,
      :turbo_trainer,
      :watt_bike
    ]
  ]
```

My params:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XX", "profile"=> 
{"gender"=>"male", "dob(1i)"=>"1927", "dob(2i)"=>"3", "dob(3i)"=>"14", 
"disciplines_attributes"=>{"0"=>
{"discipline_type"=>"swimming", "distance_in_meters_per_week"=>"", 
"equipment"=>
    {
      "pull_buoy"=>"true", 
      "paddles"=>"false", 
      "wetsuit"=>"true", 
      "fins"=>"false", 
      "tempo_trainer"=>"false"
    }}}, 
"commit"=>"Create Profile"}
```

Then my inspected resultant profile_params from the controller:

```
{"gender"=>"male", "dob(1i)"=>"1927", "dob(2i)"=>"3", "dob(3i)"=>"14", "height_in_meters"=>"", 
"disciplines_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"discipline_type"=>"swimming", "distance_in_meters_per_week"=>"", 
"equipment"=>{
    "pull_buoy"=>"true", 
    "paddles"=>"false", 
    "wetsuit"=>"true", 
    "fins"=>"false", 
    "tempo_trainer"=>"false"}}
}
```

Can someone help me understand why the equipment hash is not committed to the database?

```
Discipline id: 148, profile_id: 50, discipline_type: "running", distance_in_meters_per_week: "", sessions_per_week: nil, time_per_session_in_minutes: nil, created_at: "2017-03-14 12:02:15", updated_at: "2017-03-14 12:02:15", equipment: nil>]
```

Answer (score 0):

What is it about writing your own question, that always then leads you to finally understanding that, just maybe, you screwed up elsewhere?

Like overloading the `Disciplines::initialize` method to 'seed' the equipment hstore when it's a new record. But doing it on every instance, not just new records.

So in answer to my own question. The above does work, and if I'd bothered to check the DB directly, rather than relying on the console, I might have realised that:

```
after_initialize :setup_equipment

def initialize(search, options = {})
  self.options = options
  super
end

private

def setup_equipment
  self.equipment = self.options
end
```

Was my problem all along. :(